# Crashlytics on Android - what to import?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

ATM I have an application in the field with a working, basic Crashlytics support - I can see the crashes coming in my Firebase console.

Now, I'd like to add some custom info to the stacktraces coming. [Crashlytics docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0&platform=android)  state that I can add custom 'keys' in the following way:

```
Crashlytics.setString(key, "foo" /* string value */);
```

They however fail to mention what do I have to import here for the compiler to resolve the 'Crashlytics' symbol? Googling doesn't help....

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turned out that Crashlytics's own docs are not up-to-date. Even though [this official page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android) clearly says to do

```
Crashlytics.setString(key, "foo" /* string value */);
```

and then iike Oleg says the right import would be

```
com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics
```

but earlier on [the same Crashlytics docs page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) advises to add the following dependency

```
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics dependency.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta04'
```

where *com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics* doesn't exist.

Correct (at least at the moment, Crashlytics seems to be changing in non-compatible ways) way seems to be include the dependancy in 'build.gradle' as given above and then

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics;
(...)
FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
crashlytics.setCustomKey("key", "value" );
```

Comment: There are currently two sets of instructions available on Firebase, one for the legacy SDK ("com.crashlytics.sdk.android: crashlytics:2.10.1") and one for the beta Firebase SDK ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta04"). The instructions that you linked have the correct APIs and artifact names for the legacy SDK. If you are using the new Firebase Crashlytics SDKs, you need to follow the beta instructions. Please note that the SDK will be coming out of beta soon and the legacy instructions will be removed, so this comment may not be relevant for much longer.

Answer (score 0):

That should be resolved by this import statement

```
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
```

Comment: For the record, this is outdated. Now the correct import is  
`import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics;`

Comment: It depends if the user is still using the Fabric SDK, or has migrated to the Firebase SDK.